# Corona SDK director class passing variables between scenes

Tags: variables, sdk, coronasdk

I am trying to pass variables between scenes using the director class in Corona SDK but it wont work. What I need to do is give a set of options for the user i.e button 1, button 2, button 3. If the user selects button 1 then I need to pass a variable to the next scenes to access through an if statement. So if button 1 then display blue.jpg, if button 2 display yellow.jpg. I would really appreciate help with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to pass variables between the scenes in Rauber's Director Class, just pass them in an array in scene 1:

```
local parameters = {p1="some text", p2="some more text"}

director:changeScene(parameters, "sceneName")
```

In scene 2, make the new function accept the parameters:

```
function new(parameters)
    print(parameters.p1, parameters.p2) --> some text   some more text
end
```